# <asp:TemplateField Boxes Disappearing

Tags: asp.net

I've got a text box that just disappeared. When I add another templateField anywhere on the page, this one bizarelly disappears. Anyone know what might be up?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" SortExpression="summary">
             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblSummary" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'></asp:Label>
             </ItemTemplate>

             <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummary" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'></asp:TextBox>
             </ItemTemplate>

        </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<AnotherEdit>
```

I hope you don't take this wrong, and I mean no offense, but it seems like you're missing some of the basic concepts and need a good place to learn them.

Please check out the following article so that you fully understand how to use TemplateFields as opposed to a normal BoundField or a Command field.  I think once you "get" it, your disappearing item issues will clear up because you'll be able to see it on your own.

http://www.asp.net/learn/data-access/tutorial-12-cs.aspx

```
</AnotherEdit>
```

You can't have more than one ItemTemplate in a TemplateField.  You can have an EditItemTemplate and an ItemTemplate, though...

***Edit - Added***

The ItemTemplate shows when you're in normal display mode.
The EditItemTemplate shows when you're in edit mode
InsertItemTemplate shows when you're in Insert mode.

For any column in a GridView (or field in a FormView or field in a DetailsView) there can only be one TemplateField.
Within that TemplateField, there can only be one ItemTemplate, one EditItemTemplate, and one InsertItemTemplate (and not all three are required but all three ***are*** recommended.)

If you want the TextBox to show up next to the label in the normal non-edit mode, you would put the text box within the existing ItemTemplate as follows:

```
    <ItemTemplate>                
        <asp:Label ID="lblSummary" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'>
        </asp:Label>             
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummary" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>             
    </ItemTemplate>
```

However, the norm is to have the label when in read mode, and a text box when in edit or update mode like shown below:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Summary" SortExpression="summary">
    <ItemTemplate>                
        <asp:Label ID="lblSummary" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'>
        </asp:Label>             
    </ItemTemplate>             
    <EditItemTemplate>                
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummary" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>             
    </EditItemTemplate>        
<InsertItemTemplate>                
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtSummary" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="500" Height="100" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("summary") %>'>
        </asp:TextBox>             
    </InsertItemTemplate>        
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: whats the difference between an InsertItemTemplate and a EditItemTemplate?

Comment: put <EditItemTemplate> around the textBox fields, but TemplateField is still missing.

Comment: cool. would this explain why TemplateFields are not appearing?

Comment: removed this and it seems to work. What is this for? <asp:BoundField Visible="False" DataField="id" HeaderText="id" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" />

Comment: The id field is most likely the primary key.  You wouldn't necessarily want it displayed to the user (Visible="False") but you need it on the gridview so that when the user selects a row, the runtime can match the row up with the right record in the data source.

Comment: ok, thought it was fixed. When I removed that it caused another field to disappear. Is anyone seeing a pattern here, its like theres a limit to the amount of fields it will display at one time.

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple "ItemTemplate" declarations in there.  There should be only one.